# Phalcon PHP can't find public folder

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, phalcon

I have installed Phalcon and created a new project using:

`$ phalcon project Prestige`

When I go to `localhost/~Bartek/Prestige`, I get this error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /Users/Bartek/Sites/Prestige/public/ was not found on this server.
```

... However, the `public/` directory exists.

I'm on a Macbook Pro late 2014. I'm using preinstalled `PHP 5.5` and `Apache2`. I have installed Phalcon from `homebrew`. `mod_rewrite` is enabled as I can see in the `phpinfo()`.

---

My `Bartek.conf` file:

```
<Directory "/Users/Bartek/Sites/">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    Require all granted
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your web directory to `/Users/Bartek/Sites/Prestige/public/` and go to localhost.

If that still didn't work check your phalcon app config settings.